# PHP Date and Hours

Tags: php, date

I have this line:

```
 if (date(H) < 16) { } else { }
```

I simply am saying, `if it is before 6PM, do something`

However, it does not work.  but if I add a few numbers in it, for example,

```
 if (date(H) < 1655) {
```

A total bogus hour, it then works.  This is such a basic concept I've used before, am I missing something right in front of me here?

edit:  I am testing after 6PM in real time but am getting the results of BEFORE 6PM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `date(H)` to `date('H')`

And `6PM = 18hr`

Comment: @KickingLettuce - it happens !!

Comment: Does it respect my current, default timezone?

Comment: @KickingLettuce - it doesn't depends on the timezone. 6PM is 12hr format and 18 is 24hr format !! both the time is same

Comment: I mean, if the user does something on this website app, it checks in *their* timezone right? '18' for them is still 6PM?  Its not a static GMT time or anything like that?

Comment: No, `date()` function returns the date and time of the server. It always depends on your server timings.